# Ionic Error cannot find a differ supporting object ['Object Object] API apiCartolaFC

Tags: json, ionic-framework

My code is giving an error. I used Array and it was ok, when working with object is not accepting. Can someone help me?

Exit: cannot find a differ supporting object ['Object Object]

jogadores.html

```
<ion-content padding>
  <ion-list>
     <ion-item *ngFor="let j of jogadores">
      <p>{{j.apelido}}</p>
           <!--<h1>{{j.apelido}}</h1>
          <img src="{{j.foto}}" alt="" />-->
      </ion-item>
   </ion-list>
 </ion-content>
```

jogadores.ts

```
export class JogadoresPage {
  public jogadores: Jogador[];
  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, 
    public navParams: NavParams,
    private jogadoresService: JogadoresServiceProvider) {
      this.jogadoresService.lista().subscribe(
        (jogador) =>{
          this.jogadores = jogador;
          }

      );
  }

  ionViewDidLoad() {
    console.log('ionViewDidLoad JogadoresPage');
  }

}
```

jogadores-service.ts

```
@Injectable()
export class JogadoresServiceProvider {
  pathbase = "apicartola"
  constructor(public http: HttpClient,
    private _platform: Platform) {
      if(this._platform.is("cordova")){
        this.pathbase = "https://api.cartolafc.globo.com";
      }
    console.log('Hello JogadoresServiceProvider Provider');
  }
  lista(){
    return this.http.get<Jogador[]>(this.pathbase + '/atletas/pontuados')
  }
}
```

mymodel jogador.ts

```
export interface Jogador{
    apelido: string;
    foto: string;
    //atletas:any[];
}
```

Comment: Can you add your HTTP request response?

Comment: RROR Error: Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'object'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays.
    at NgForOf.ngOnChanges (common.js:2579)
    at checkAndUpdateDirectiveInline (core.js:12407)
    at checkAndUpdateNodeInline (core.js:13935)
    at checkAndUpdateNode (core.js:13878)
    at debugCheckAndUpdateNode (core.js:14771)
    at debugCheckDirectivesFn (core.js:14712)
    at Object.eval [as updateDirectives] (JogadoresPage.html:18)
    at Object.debugUpdateDirectives [as updateDirectives] (core.js:14697)
    ...

Comment: is this the error provided by the request? it doesn't returns the object? Console.log your `jogadores`, what does it prints?

Comment: Hello JogadoresServiceProvider Provider
jogadores.ts:33 ionViewDidLoad JogadoresPage